# Invalid read of size 4, valgrind fscanf

Tags: c

I am working on an assignement but ran into a strange problem while debugging.

```
==30771== Invalid read of size 4
==30771==   at 0x4E9CC5D: __isoc99_fscanf (isoc99_fscanf.c:30)
==30771==   by 0x400728: main main.c:13)
==30771== Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I cant for the life of me figure out why I get this error in valgrind. The code works except for this.

I made a test project to isolate the error:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("../map1.map", "r");

    char *buff = malloc(51*sizeof(char));

    //Scanning for the amount of edges.
    if (fscanf(myFile, "%s", buff) != 1){
        printf("Something is wrong\n");
    }

    printf("%s", buff);

    fclose(myFile);

    char str[20];
    scanf("%s", str);
}
```

The file looks like this:

```c
9
Nod1 Nod2
```

It compiles correctly and prints 9.

Compiled with these settings:

```c
gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -O0 main.c -o myProgram
```

run in valgrind with these settings:

```c
valgrind --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes ./myProgram
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you're not checking the result of `fopen`

Comment: Why you don't check that `malloc()` did not return `NULL` and that `fopen()` didn't return `NULL` either. Also, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: if you allocate 51 bytes, then use `if (fscanf(myFile, "%50s", buff) != 1){` it's safer

Comment: Sorry, most of this has already been tried. My head is a mess. Il edit the post.

Comment: @JoelHansson Please try to execute my version of your program, it only has slight modifications, but you should not see any `valgrind` message. And if you do, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: "Invalid read of size 4 ... __isoc99_fscanf (isoc99_fscanf.c:30)" `fopen()` returned `NULL`.

Comment: Is `scanf("%s", str);` the _true_ code?

Comment: The downvoter should check the comments on my answer, just in case it is accepted and then I can't delete it though it will still have the downvote there.

Comment: The thing in the end is just to stop the program from instantly turning of. It can be ignored. It works if I add tests to see if it returns NULL. But the code ran fine so it never actually returned NULL.

Comment: i suggest that this is most likely a harmless message which is a result of the optimization design of the function. Most likely they are reading something in 32 or 64 bit quantities. whether some bytes are outside of an allocated region. I see a lot of those from different libc functions in perfectly good programs.

Comment: @JoelHansson, Something was `NULL` somewhere and it's at the call to `fscanf()`. Try with `--track-origins=yes` and post the full output of valgrind please.

Comment: You are correct. The filepath was different when I compiled it in the terminal from where I ran it in the IDE resulting in a NULL. This is why you do the tests I guess. I just feel stupid now.

Comment: Search for "Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd" with the search engine of your choice. Pretty sure that you get valuable hints and explanations.

Comment: @JoelHansson my first comment was giving the solution :)

Comment: The problem is solved now btw. Dont know if I can click a checkbox or anything. 

I tried searching and didnt find anything simple enough for me to understand.

Comment: @JoelHansson If you had tested, then you would immediately know that the file path was wrong. So ALWAYS test for errors, it saves a lot of time, contrary to what you might be thinking when faced with writing code to do so. It also avoids some mysterious things. If you make sure that there is no possibility for UB then you can debug your programs without some [heisenbugs](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) happening.

Comment: Im not that experienced. I will check for errors from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the concept of *undefined behavior*, if you are not very careful you can trigger such undefined behavior and then, you wont be able to tell whether the program *is working* or not.

I will post some code that I consider very robust and should not cause any *valgrind* reports at all, including the removal of the last statement which is doing nothing, every thing I changed was **a probable the reason for the problem**.

You MUST check that every function succeeded when they return a value, a more robust version of your own program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    const char *filepath;
    char *buffer;

    filepath = "../map1.map";
    file = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error openning: %s\n", filepath);
        return -1;
    }

    buffer = malloc(51);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error, memory exhausted\n");
        fclose(file);

        return -1;
    }


    // Scanning for the amount of edges.
    if (fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) != 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "error, cannot read from the file\n");
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", buffer);
    }
    // Release all resources
    fclose(file);
    free(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

If you run this code with *valgrind* chances are that *0* errors will be reported regardless of whether the file exists or not. But you must be careful with,

```
fscanf(file, "%s", buffer)
```

because it can overflow `buffer`, so instead tell `fscanf()` to read a given number of bytes like this

```
fscanf(file, "%50s", buffer)
```

this, lets `fscanf()` scanf at most `50` bytes and leaves space for the terminating `null` character.

Comment: Not my DV but `fscanf(file, "%s", buffer)` does **not** mean that *valgrind* chances 0 errors.

Comment: This works. Can you explain why I get the error in my code? Or link me to something explaining it.

Comment: @JoelHansson Sadly, no! I can't. There is a concept called *undefined* behavior, if you run into it then magic things could happen. For instance, the code might seem to work but *valgrind* reports a problem WTF? Yes it's undefined so virtually ANYTHING can happen.

Comment: @JoelHansson Also, the valgrind error means dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, because it says *address 0x0*.

Comment: @JoelHansson And add `--track-origins=yes` to your *valgrind* command line.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I changed some things in my original code. I guess valgrind gets cranky if you dont do all of these checks.

Comment: @JoelHansson *valgrind* simply reports memory errors, it doesn't care about your checks, it is that your checks prevent these errors.

Comment: NMDV, but this sounds like cargo cult programming. UB is an important concept of the C standard, but shouldn't be an excuse not to understand what's going on. After compilation there's no magic - the CPU will do as told; valgrind checks are no black magic as well. OP's code is surely lacking in error checking, but AFAICT if the file is present and the lines are as short as they are, it should work fine. The right course of action in these cases is to get your hands dirty with the debugger and actually *understand* what's going on, not just moving stuff hoping to scare away the problem.

Comment: @MatteoItalia It's weird that I am actually familiar with the concept of the cargo cult because as far as I know it's not a wide spread idea, and it applies to our governments a lot in Venezuela, so that's how I know the concept. But UB might be something that causes undetectable problems and that's why it should be avoided. It's not just *avoiding it in the hope that nothing goes wrong*, there is no hope involved. If you avoid it then there will be no mysteries.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a surprisingly widespread "debug" technique - there's a problem I don't understand, let's move around stuff until it goes away; that's a *terrible* habit to pick, especially in a language that has so much UB as C; if you didn't understand what was the problem in first place, how can you know that you actually removed it, and you didn't just hide it in a darker place?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: UB lies in every corner of C, even programmers with tens of years of experience fall in its traps; from your own admission you don't know what was the original problem in OP's code, which superficially looks correct; how can you know for sure that your code, which has more checks, but doesn't look particularly different from the original, is now UB free? Maybe you just managed to hide it better from valgrind, or avoided it in some code path. But again, the problem is not much this specific example, it's one of methodology. If valgrind cries, you get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Because I am preventing every possibility for it by checking every possible `NULL` pointer dereference and avoiding a buffer overflow at `fscanf()`. That's how I know for sure. If it was a more complicated program, then there is always a risk that one missed something and UB will occur anyway of course.

Comment: I downvoted at first because it didn't answer the question. Now that OP revealed (what a surprise) that he wasn't running the code from the same directory, I reverted & upvoted (& downvoted question, to be perfectly honest). I was tempted to answer about this NULL `FILE *` at first but refrained to do so because I hadn't enough elements to be sure it answered.

Comment: also, it may happen that I "hide stuff under the carpet" when I have non-reproducible crashes. But after a while, the crash happens 100% of the time: then it's much easier to debug.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre From my experience, writing code without checking errors is always a cause of mysterious errors. That's why I answered.

Comment: the devotion of Iharob in his comments also deserves some reward :)

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi okay, but that's more a "codereview" answer. Improving OP code isn't really answering. Well, never mind now.